# Android studio gradle build error: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/.../.jar' in company firewall

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have added below mentioned list of URL's in proxy exception list in company firewall i.e:

- plugins.gradle.org;
- repo1.maven.org;
- maven.google.com;
- dl.google.com;
- jcenter.bintray.com;
- repo.maven.apache.org;

but during gradle syncing giving an error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:476)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/dce7e66b32456a1b1198da0caff3a8acb71548658391e798c79369241e6490a4?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvZGNlN2U2NmIzMjQ1NmExYjExOThkYTBjYWZmM2E4YWNiNzE1NDg2NTgzOTFlNzk4Yzc5MzY5MjQxZTY0OTBhND9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnByb3RvYnVmLWphdmEtMy40LjAuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNTc5NTMwNzM3fSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=HDZMRseQdleb~-x2bgDRyz5YikjnfSY00OnzU96M8oxr8GoFUPnlefKf5HrOa6uuJCgagpw-CJgTaCvEo4KCpenCSt-CxXTiVva-HlIGEtOGqNBBII1jI4OUGMR682sRoMCLflqL6J-rikEPIncm3b7c7V~L5rsMx9ruVvShNjBodAVake6U-JbibcxKffUnUH5odL0DLGfijb9sRssjMbnnJxa0hcQxnvGVgrgK2d9pRBlDB3otxEEWC6DDGzuUoToTvpSnJ4j9kj2CqKbQ5XOAa0~nXvVRQUtyCs5IwCK-~IvaQKqkZhiTE31nPWDDvEmw57dHEp1Zyn6JjnfQ2g__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net:443 [d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.224.197.54, d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.224.197.182, d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.224.197.39, d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.224.197.100] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:89)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 66 more
```

Please help how can I handle a dynamic URL as mentioned in the above logs.
I have also set Android studio and windows proxy settings to no Proxy because of my company firewall bypass above URL's and treat as no proxy. let me know in case of any other info needed.

Comment: will you please add some more details? which exact steps you have followed to rectify this problem?

Comment: My Network is proxy based, I added URL's in proxy Exception list and Firewall bypass proxy Exception list URL's. and I think due to dynamic urls creation by gradle syncing as mentioned in question logs not able to connect with server. 
and I don't know how to handle dynamic urls. @amitpandya

Comment: @ZeeshanAkhtar did you find the solution for this problem i'm also facing same issue.

Comment: @YBDevi currently not able to resolve this issue. meanwhile, I sync my Gradle by requesting to Network team for direct internet access.

Answer (score 8):

In Android Studio
Go Settings>Tools>Server Certificates
Check the "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically" option and apply. This was work for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already checked this, but not working getting same error.

Comment: @bilekmeckik i have try  your solution but it is not worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` in all your build.gradle files.

As mentioned in [migrating away from JCenter guide](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2021/02/04/migratingjcenter/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by following below procudere

In Mac goto

Preference->build,execution,Deployment->Gradle->Android studio
checked "Enable embedded Maven repository".

after this if you still face issue with gradle build.
add below in root project

```
 repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
//        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://maven.google.com" }//Required for crashlytics
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The pom file is downloaded from jcenter.bintray.com. As shown in the error log, the jar file is redirected to d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net and downloaded. Try add d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net as a firewall exception.